# way to validate a set of dates in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have a set of dates and I am using the below approach to validate them. I want to confirm if using so many try-except blocks is the right way of doing it or there is some better approach?

Also, the date could be in some other format as well like dd/mm/yyyy, so am I supposed to include every possible format or there is some better way of doing it?

```
dob="""
10/23/1964
9/14/2010
12-23-98
"""

try:
    date_time= datetime.strptime(dob, '%m/%d/%Y')
except:
       try:
           date_time= datetime.strptime(dob, '%m-%d-%Y')
       except:
              try:
                  date_time= datetime.strptime(dob, '%m/%d/%y')
              except:
                     try:
                         date_time= datetime.strptime(dob, '%m-%d-%y') 
                     except:
                            date_time="invalid date"
print(date_time)
```

Comment: I think you can use the regular expressions [regexp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for different date formats and validate using them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by [@Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist):

```
dob = '''
10/23/1964
9/14/2010
12-23-98
'''

def validate(sdatetime):
    for pattern in [
        '%m/%d/%Y',
        '%m-%d-%Y',
        '%m/%d/%y',
        '%m-%d-%y',
    ]:
        try:
            # return upon success
            return datetime.strptime(sdatetime, pattern)
        except ValueError:
            pass
            # handle the error if you want

    return "invalid date"

for line in dob.splitlines():
    if line:
        print(line, validate(line))
```

---

The original post:

```
dob = '''
10/23/1964
9/14/2010
12-23-98
'''

def validate(sdatetime):
    for fn in [
        lambda sdatetime: datetime.strptime(sdatetime, '%m/%d/%Y'),
        lambda sdatetime: datetime.strptime(sdatetime, '%m-%d-%Y'),
        lambda sdatetime: datetime.strptime(sdatetime, '%m/%d/%y'),
        lambda sdatetime: datetime.strptime(sdatetime, '%m-%d-%y'),
        lambda sdatetime: "invalid date"
    ]:
        try:
            # return upon success
            return fn(sdatetime)
        except ValueError:
            pass
            # handle the error if you want

for line in dob.splitlines():
    if line:
        print(line, validate(line))
```

Comment: I would suggest only putting the patterns in the list and using`for`'s `else` clause to return the invalid message